# making an indicator variable that assigns 1 to the first time to record a negative number, grouped by id in r

Tags: r, panel, indicator

| id | time | value | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2004 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2005 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2006 | -1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2007 | -3 | 0 |
| 1 | 2008 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2004 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2005 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2006 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2007 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2004 | -1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2005 | -3 | 0 |
| 3 | 2006 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 2007 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 2004 | 4 | 0 |
| 4 | 2005 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 2006 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 2007 | -4 | 1 |

I want to make an indicator variable that takes a value of 1 only for the first time an id has a negative value for the first time. I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance ; )

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator = +(replace(value<0, which(value < 0)[1], 2) == 2))

# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   id [4]
      id  time value indicator
   <int> <int> <int>     <int>
 1     1  2004     1         0
 2     1  2005     0         0
 3     1  2006    -1         1
 4     1  2007    -3         0
 5     1  2008     3         0
 6     2  2004     1         0
 7     2  2005     3         0
 8     2  2006     0         0
 9     2  2007     0         0
10     3  2004    -1         1
11     3  2005    -3         0
12     3  2006     4         0
13     3  2007     5         0
14     4  2004     4         0
15     4  2005     5         0
16     4  2006     2         0
17     4  2007    -4         1
```

Comment: thx buddy! May I ask you the functions of 2 as the third argument in the replace function and after logical operator ==?